# How do I resolve a SpEl equation containing properties in a unit test?

Tags: spring, unit-testing, spring-el

I would like to use the SpEl parser to evaluate an expression in a unit test.

I have this lengthy expression

```
(!(${security.exclude.disable:false} && ${security.exclude.disable:true}) && (!${security.exclude.swagger.disable:false} && ${security.exclude.swagger.disable:true})) || !(${security.exclude.swagger.disable:false} && ${security.exclude.swagger.disable:true})
```

I would like to write a unit test that I can pass in different property values and validate that this expression.

This is what I have been doing, but I get errors, and I don't see how I can pass in the different properties.

```
ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();
Expression exp = parser.parseExpression(expression);
String message = (String) exp.getValue();
```

Comment: What are the errors?

Answer (score 0):

> but I get errors,

You should generally show the actual errors when asking questions like this.

Try

```
'${security.exclude.disable:false}'.toLowerCase() == 'true'
```

etc. Or

```
Boolean.parseBoolean('${security.exclude.disable:false}')
```